# L_ERRORCODE0:10409 Express Checkout token was issued for a merchant account other than yours

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

> L_ERRORCODE0:10409 Express Checkout token was issued for a merchant
>   account other than yours

What is this error means?
I didn't understand the cause of this ERROR in my application
 when i integrate paypal express checkout.

Answer (score 6):

I'm assuming you must have gotten that when calling DoExpressCheckoutPayment..??

The only reason I can think that you would get this is if you're using different API credentials for SetExpressCheckout than you used in DoExpressCheckoutPayment.

Or, it could be that when you called SetExpressCheckout you were using a SUBJECT value and you forgot to include this same value in your DoExpressCheckoutPayment request.

That's all I can think of that would raise that error, because it really does mean exactly what it says...the token is for a different account than you're trying to process the payment with.